# NETMF Deployment Issue

Tags: .net-micro-framework

I have developed a netmf application and I want to deploy and test the application on my laptop
but I get the following error :

```
Error: a3000000

The program '[1] Micro Framework application: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Waiting for debug commands...
```

when I deploy the program on my friends laptop I don't get the error , I thought the error might be related to installation of Gadgeteer sdk therefor I reinstalled the sdk several times but I steel get the same error

Any ideas what could be wrong  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found It , the issue was that the device firmware  was not update and I updated my firmware using
 `MFDeploy.exe` 
tool which is in directoy :
 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Micro Framework\v4.2\Tools`
Now everything works like a charm